# How can I execute multiple methods at once in a laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dashboard page where I want to display multiple functionalities like displaying a form, showing a list of articles from database.

But, since routes can allow only one method to run at a time for each route, how can I achieve it?

I want to do something like this

```
Route::get('/dashboard','Dashboard@index');
Route::get('/dashboard','Dashboard@showArticles');
Route::get('/dashboard','Dashboard@showUsersList');
```

I know this doesn't work, but what is the alternative? Since I want to do all this on the same page.

Comment: Nope. The route calls the specified method. Use the method to trigger the functionalities you want. For example make your Dashboard@index method combine the functionality of index, articles and users. It's not the responsibility of the router.

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine all methods in single method like this and pass it to view

```
public function getIndex()
{
  $users = User::all();
  $articles = Articles::all();
  return view('page.your_view')->with('users', $users)->with('articles', 'articles'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by using,

```
public function index()
{
  $users = User::all();
  $articles = Articles::all();
  return view('page.your_view', compact(['users' => $users, 'articles' => 'articles']); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{?type}','Dashboard@index');
```

In controller

```
public function getIndex($type)
{
    if(isset($type) && !empty($type) && $type=='article'){ 
           return $this->article();
    }
  return view('page.index'); 
}
public function article(){
       ...YOUR CODE
}
```